# How to load fragments in Tab layout in certain order so that I can reduce app launch time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, rss

I have tab layout with 5 tabs each has separate fragments, first fragment displays RSS News feed which are fetched from server, this news fragment takes lot of time to load so I re-arranged in such a way that news fragment at the end. But still it takes same time to launch the app. I need some help to load cut down the launch time by showing less loaded fragmented tab at first.

This is my Tab Layout activity, here is my code \

```
 public class NewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        String user_retr_password=null;
        String newpassword;
        String dobstr;
        String currentdate;
        Boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        String id,regid;
        String mobileno;

        Session se;
        UserInfo UInfo;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private int[] tabIcons = {

                R.drawable.news123,
                R.drawable.notification,
                R.drawable.club3,
                R.drawable.myspaces
                R.drawable.Home
        };

        ImageButton userImage_ImageButton;
        Bitmap UserImage = null;
        Context context;
        Point p;
        public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

        RelativeLayout LoadingPanel;
        int TabSelected = 0;

        public static LocationManager locationManager;
        public static LocationListener locationListener;

        static List<AdvertizementTableModel.AdvInfo> Adv_List = new ArrayList<AdvertizementTableModel.AdvInfo>();
        static List<Bitmap> AdvertizementImagesList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        PopupWindow popup;
        WebView Adv_myWebView;
        static PopupWindow popupWebView = null;
        static AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        static boolean activeActivity = false;

        private GoogleApiClient client;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.newactivity);
            context = getApplicationContext();

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            UInfo = (UserInfo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UInfo");


            try {
                Date dob = UInfo.getDateOfBirth();
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                dobstr = df.format(dob);
            }catch(Exception e){}

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            currentdate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            mobileno=UInfo.getMobile().toString();

            TabSelected = (Integer) getIntent().getIntExtra("TAB", 0);

            userImage_ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.userImage_ImageButton);
            LoadingPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoadingPanel_NewActivity);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            Adv_myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.rsscategory_tabs);
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);



            LoadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            registerInBackground();

            userImage_ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPopup(aappen.com.buddiesnew.NewActivity.this, p);

                }
            });

           GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

            try {

                checkEnteryinUser();
                checkEnteryinUserprofile();
                getIdRegId(UInfo.getMobile());

            }catch(Exception e){

            }

            retrievepasswordfromphp();
        }
```

registerinBackground() method code

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";

            setUserPicFromSqlite();

            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    setupViewPager(viewPager);
                    setupTabIcons();
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);   
                }

            });


            ViewTreeObserver vto = userImage_ImageButton.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    userImage_ImageButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    width = userImage_ImageButton.getMeasuredHeight();
                    height = userImage_ImageButton.getMeasuredWidth();


                    Bitmap circleBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(UserImage, width - 2);
                    userImage_ImageButton.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            LoadingPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            LoadingPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            getAdvertizementDetailsInBackgroundFromSqlite();


        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

onPostExcute has this code

```
 private void setupTabIcons() {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
        final NewActivity.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new NewActivity.ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment7(), "News");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment2(), "Message");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment4(), "Club");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment0(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment5(), "My Space");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(TabSelected);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }


ViewPager adapter



class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Tab Layout 0 [which gets news feed]

```
 public class TabFragment0 extends Fragment {

        UserInfo UInfo;
        Context context;
        ImageButton EditImageButton;
        Bitmap ImageBitmap = null, LogoBitmap=null;

        int width;
        int height;

        TableLayout tl;
        TableRow tr;
        ImageView RssurlImageView;
        Bitmap RssImageBitmap;
        ImageView RssSourceImage;
        Activity context1;
        WebView mWebview;
        ImageButton closeWebView_Button, RssCategoryEdit_Button,share_ImageButton;
        List<RSSMasterInfo> RSSMasterList = new ArrayList<RSSMasterInfo>();
        String Names,Urls,Imagelinks;
        String[] newsnames, newsurls, newslogo;
        List<String> NewsNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> NewsUrlsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> NewsLogoList = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<RSSMasterInfo.RssfeedSubCategoryLink> RssLinkForOnTouch = new ArrayList<RSSMasterInfo.RssfeedSubCategoryLink>();
        RSSMasterInfo.RssfeedSubCategoryLink rssOnTouchInfo = new RSSMasterInfo.RssfeedSubCategoryLink();
        ScrollView scrollview;
        ImageButton reloadImageButton;
        int finalImagecount = 0;
        static boolean activeActivity = false;
        static Boolean UpdateImagesFlag = false;
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRss;
        boolean isItPrinted = false;
        String Link=null;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_0, null, false);
            UInfo = (UserInfo) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UInfo");
            EditImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Rss_EditImageButton);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rssfeed_relativelayout);
            tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rsstablelayout);
            reloadImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ReloadImages_ImageButton);
            mWebview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.rssFeed_WebView);
            closeWebView_Button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.closeWebView_Button);
            RssCategoryEdit_Button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Rss_EditImageButton);
            scrollview = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainscrollView);
            share_ImageButton=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.share_ImageButton);

            // swipeRss = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipreRssRefresh);
            mWebview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            closeWebView_Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            share_ImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            context1 = getActivity();




            deleteRssImages();
            RssSourceImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.RssSourceImageView);

            finalImagecount = 0; //Returns the number of STATIC IMAGES i.e The Images that are loaded when there is no RSS FEED.


            reloadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            reloadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    reloadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tryGetNewFeed();


                }
            });


            scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    onTouchEvent(event);
                    return false;
                }
            });


            return view;

        }


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            try {
                //startFeedTab();
                getFinalRSSfeeds();  //this gets Rss news feed.....
                // tryGetNewFeed();

            } catch (Exception e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        activeActivity = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can perform the request once you open the app and save the fetched data using DB or sharedPreferences and once the user opens the tab show the stored data.
That's a solution, I think I did something like this before, but it was with list of images and it worked.

You can also try a network library that can fetch the data faster than the native AsyncTask, such as: [Fast Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) or [Android Asynchronous Http Client](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) etc.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the app launch time, you can follow a basic approach.

You can create a fake fragment with no views, and later replace it with your original fragments after a certain delay.

In you `pagerAdapter` `getItem()`, you can modify as below:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == TAB_ONE) {
            if (Utility.isEmpty(fragmentOne)) {
                //Here I pass the fragment to be loaded along with the delay, i.e. 50ms
                fragmentOne = FragmentFake.create(new FragmentOne(), 50);
            }
            return fragment;
        } else if (position == TAB_TWO) {
            if (Utility.isEmpty(fragmentTwo)) {
                //FragmentTwo created with a delay of 100ms
                fragmentTwo = FragmentFake.create(new FragmentOne(), 100);
            }
            return fragmentTwo;
        } else if (position == TAB_THREE) {
            if (Utility.isEmpty(fragmentThree)) {
                //FragmentThree created with a delay of 100ms
                fragmentThree = FragmentFake.create(new FragmentThree(), 150);
            }
            return fragmentThree;
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

And your **`FragmentFake`** class will be like:

```
public class FragmentFake extends Fragment {

private View root;
Fragment fragment;

public static Fragment create(Fragment frag, int timeMs) {
    FragmentFake fragmentFake = new FragmentFake();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    fragmentFake.fragment = frag;
    bundle.putInt("time", timeMs);
    fragmentFake.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragmentFake;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fake_fragment, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    replaceFragment(bundle.getInt("time"));
    return root;
}

//Replacing fragments with a delay
private void replaceFragment(int time) {
    root.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!isAdded()){
                return;
            }
            if (!Utility.isEmpty(fragment)) {
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.replace_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        }
    }, time);
}
}
```

**Utility.java**

```
public class Utility {
  public static boolean isEmpty(Object object) {
    return object == null;
  }
}
```

The `FragmentFake`layout is just a `FrameLayout`that will contain the replaced fragments

**fragment_fake_layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/replace_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for spending your valuable time to help me out of this problem. but the problem is with that RSS feed fragment which is eating up my app's launch time so i don't want to load that fragment at launch time,if i 
 will be able to load less loaded fragment at launch then i can load the news feed fragment at the last, i don't think i can achieve it if i uses View Pager. Do u have any idea? if yes let me know. and i don't know how this fake fragment trick work but definitely ill try out. Thank you man for your valuable reply.

Comment: may I know what's Utility In that code? if its a class then please post the code for Utility class. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is just a helper class to check if the object is null. I added the class in the edit

Comment: That is an instance of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`